# find an expression for the sum of the ith row of the pattern, and then prove its correctness

Tags: sequences-and-series

[image: Consider the following triangle]

Prove that the relation hidden in the above triangle holds for any number of rows. 
Hint:find an expression for the sum of the ith
row, and then prove its correctness.

Comment: expression for the sum: $i^3$?

Comment: expression for i row

Answer (score 2):

i think you need something like this.

first number of $r$ th row is $r^2-r+1$ and the last one is $r^2+r-1$

so sum of $r$ th rows terms is $r\cdot\frac{(r^2-r+1)+(r^2+r-1)}{2}=r^3$